# How can I disable remembering of password inputs by the browser

Tags: asp.net, security

How can I disable remembering of password inputs by the browser with asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways that you can achieve this.
For example you can use `HTML5`.
In HTML 5 you can use [auto complete](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_form_autocomplete.asp) on or off.

```
 eg.  <form autocomplete="on|off">
```

Also have a look at the article about [AUTOCOMPLETE Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486%28VS.85%29.aspx)